# Update Trigger With Repeated Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have created a trigger which will update the doctype with the DateTime stamp.below is my code

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DocTypeChangeTracking] ON [dbo].[master]
AFTER  UPDATE
AS
declare @MasKey int;
declare @DocType varchar(100);

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT @MasKey=(SELECT i.MAS_KEY FROM INSERTED i )
IF ( UPDATE(PASSP_ISU) OR UPDATE(PASSP_EXP))
SET @DocType ='Passport'
IF ( UPDATE(RES_ISU) OR UPDATE(RES_EXP))
SET @DocType ='Residency'
IF ( UPDATE(LAB_ID_ISU) OR UPDATE(LAB_ID_EXP))
SET @DocType ='LaborID'
IF ( UPDATE(Emirates_ID_Issue_Date) OR UPDATE(Emirates_ID_Expiry_Date))
SET @DocType ='EmiratesID'
BEGIN
INSERT dbo.tblDocTypeChangeTracking
(
    MasKey,
    DocType,
    DateModified
)
SELECT @MasKey,@DocType,GETDATE() 
END
```

The problem is when any of the expiry date is update it is inserting records in tracking table with null values. I just need one record per doctype on the same date. how to resolve this issue.

```
ID  Mas_Key DocType DateModified
1   NULL    NULL    2018-11-01
2   NULL    NULL    2018-11-01
3   NULL    NULL    2018-11-01
4   NULL    NULL    2018-11-01
5   73  Passport    2018-11-01
```

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: i am using SQL server

Comment: The bigger issue is that you're ignoring multi-row updates. `inserted` is a *table*. It contains 1 row for each row affected by an update. That means it may contain 0, 1 or multiple rows. You're acting as if it contains exactly 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a query that works with *sets*, not try to do things procedurally. `inserted` and `deleted` are psuedo-tables containing as many rows as were affected by the operation that caused the trigger to fire. This can easily be more than *1*. Also, `UPDATE()` answers a different question to what I think you're trying to ask (It just effectively tells you if that column was mentioned in the `SET` clause, not whether the value has changed).

So, I'd write something like:

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DocTypeChangeTracking] ON [dbo].[master]
AFTER  UPDATE
AS
declare @MasKey int;
declare @DocType varchar(100);

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT dbo.tblDocTypeChangeTracking
(
    MasKey,
    DocType,
    DateModified
)
SELECT
    i.mas_key,
    DocType,
    GETDATE()
from
    inserted i
        inner join
    deleted d
        on
            i.mas_key = d.mas_key
        cross join
    (values(1,'Passport'), (2,'Residency')) t(ID,DocType)
where
    (t.ID = 1 and i.passp_isu != d.passp_isu) or
    (t.ID = 2 and i.res_isu != d.res_isu)
```

You'll note also that if, say, both `passp_isu` and `res_isu` have changed in any particular row, we produce *two* rows to insert into `tblDocTypeChangeTracking`.

Now, the above is incomplete for two reasons. First, I've not listed out all of the conditions for each `DocType`, nor every `DocType` yet - I leave that as an exercise for you. In addition, I've assumed that `passp_isu`, etc, aren't nullable and/or that we don't need to detect `null` -> `not null` changes (and vice versa). In standard SQL, I'd be able to write `i.passp_isu is different from d.passp_isu` to perform a "`null` aware" difference check. Unfortunately, in SQL Server, this isn't yet supported, so if you need to support such checks, you need to write each comparison as:

```
(i.passp_isu != d.passp_isu or
i.passp_isu is null and d.passp_isu is not null or
i.passp_isu is not null and d.passp_isu is null)
```

Which is far less pretty.

Comment: Thank you very much, Damien. your solution resolved my issue.this is what i am look for.

Comment: hi please help me to clarify this thing if both passp_isu and res_isu  changed in any particular row, it does not produce two rows to insert into tblDocTypeChangeTracking.how I can modify the script

Comment: @lightcoder - it should do. The whole reason for the slightly weird `cross join` and `where` clause is to be able to conjure from between 0 and 4 rows out of a single row in `inserted`, if multiple transitions have occurred in that row.

Comment: thanks it is working there was a silly change i made which was causing the issue